# How to properly use MediaWiki with $wgDBadminuser?

Tags: ssl, sql, mediawiki, x509

I have to set up a fresh MediaWiki and am getting increasingly upset with config recommendations that don't seem to work well when configured as outlined in the official documentation.

**Two servers**. One nginx webserver for the app. One mariadb for the database. Installed and configured MediaWiki on the webserver. Installed and configured mariadb on the database server.
Created an exclusive mediawiki db user let's call them `mediawiki@nginx`.
Created an exclusive mediawiki db admin user let's call them `mediawikiadmin@nginx`.

I created a **self-signed CA** on the db server to properly harden communication and altered the mentioned db users to `REQUIRE X509`.
To set this up with MediaWiki there's not many options provided. In fact the only officially mentioned choice with self-signed certs is to use the $wgDBservers object in LocalSettings. Fine. So my setup looks like this:

```
$wgDBservers = [
    [
        'host' => "mariadb",
        'dbname' => "mediawiki",
        'user' => "mediawiki",
        'password' => "pleasedontdothis",
        'type' => "mysql",
        'flags' => DBO_DEFAULT | DBO_SSL,
        'sslKeyPath' => "/path/to/nginx_private.key",
        'sslCertPath' => "/path/to/nginx.crt",
        'sslCAFile' => "/path/to/mariadb_ca.crt",
        'load' => 0,
    ]
];
$wgDBname = "mediawiki";
$wgDBprefix = "";
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";
```

This is according to the offical docs [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBservers) and [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBserver#See_also). Note how you are forced to keep a duplicate config entry of the database name. This is explained in [important notes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBservers#Important_notes) in the docs.
I personally keep these settings outside of the web root in an include which does not matter for the sake of this issue.

## The actual problem

**Updates**.
This is what it boils down to. The above setup works perfectly fine as far as the actual wiki goes. In fact I can even run `php ./maintenance/run.php update` from CLI. But here is where things start to upset me a lot.

What does **not** work in this state?

- GUI Updates from `http(s)://media.wiki/mw-config..` using `$wgUpgradeKey`.

  What happens?
- The freaking mediawiki software tries to connect to the database with default user settings!
  `Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'wikiuser'@'localhost'`.
  Well cheers, guess what, my database is on a remote server, and I told you so. And I also told you who to connect with, and how to do so in your config settings. *And you are actually able to do so running the wiki just fine*...

You'd expect the user from `$wgDBservers` be used here... I was suspecting permissions somewhere, but changes I make in LocalSettings do reflect in the error output in this step, so I do sort of ruled this out for now. LocalSettings is readable only by the webserver (and root apparently).

 Now let's get even funkier. I add the admin user that's recommended in the [offical docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Security#Maintenance_scripts):

```
$wgDBadminuser = "mediawikiadmin";
$wgDBadminpassword = "idareyoutrythis";
```

At this point everything goes just insane. I manually tested connectivity to the database with this user from CLI using all the paranoia security I set up, including TLSv1.3 only, X509 and only from this one host. The database is set up fine, this user can in fact connect.
What happens?

- Now suddenly the GUI update tries to connect with `'mediawikiadmin'@'localhost'`??
- Running the very same CLI command from earlier, the udpate script now suddenly throws an error on line 154 in ../includes/libs/rdbms/ServerInfo.php:
  `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Duplicate server name "mediawikidb" in ...` This is fixed by removing the adminuser from the settings!!
- I can force the GUI update to use the correct remote server by *also* adding the `$wgDBserver` *(singular!)* variable back into the mix, which results in duplicate configuration!!
  And even by doing so, it *still* gets an access denied error for `'mediawikiadmin'@'nginx'`, even though this is actually the right user and this database admin user can connect perfectly fine from outside of MediaWiki!
  Please remember, all this is happening while the usual database user is running the Wiki just fine...

## TL;DR

Does anyone have a ***working*** MediaWiki configuration, ***including updates***, with a properly **separated database**, using **TLS** for the SQL Client/Server communication and **setting the** `$wgDBadminuser`?
I would be fine with dropping the admin user too, but I can't get that to work either with this setup. *(see above, update scripts default to wrong user settings)*